# Show the posts which have specific tags or categories

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to show the posts which have specific tags or categories as I mentioned in the title; for example, one of my posts has 3 tags "php","laravel","regex" I want to get those posts that have laravel tag in their many to many relationships.

Comment: Looks like you need `union` query to be able to paginate through different models.

Comment: @hamed you need a list of posts that have a specific ORMRoute and a specific tag name. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah @MortezaRajabi .. Tha's right .

Comment: You can't do it using eloquent. Just a query.

Comment: in other words you want the posts with a specific route or tag is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have set the right relations on your models. then use [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). So, you can:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($tags) use ($tagName) {
        $tags->where('name', $tagName);
    })
    ->whereHas('ORMRoute', functions ($routes) use ($routeName) {
        $routes->where('route', $routeName);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: @hame I don't know what is the name of the relation between your post and ORMRoute. So, I used ORMRoute. you should use its relation name instead.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer leftJoin than whereHas because whereHas is very slow.

Try this  query and see the difference:

```
$posts = Post::leftJoin('post_tags', 'post_tags.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
             ->leftJoin('post_routes', 'post_routes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
             ->where('name', $tagName)
             ->where('route', $routeName)
             ->get();
```